# Dictionary with limited number of types

Tags: c#

First, excuse the rather funny name of my question. I'm no native speaker and it took me 10 minutes to express my thoughts in these few characters.

What I'm trying to do is to create a dictionary in C# that allows the value to be either an `int`, a `string` or a `bool`. What first had come to my mind was using generics, but as far as I know, I can only define one type as possible value-type, not "be one of those". Using `object` would also be possible, but boxing seems to be quite a performance-killer.

Is there any way to do this?

Here's a sample of what has come to my mind:

```
Dictionary<string, (string, int, bool)> foo = new Dictionary<string, (string, int, bool)>();
foo.Add("key1", "Hello, World!"); //Correct - Value is a string
foo.Add("key2", 37); //Correct - Value is an int
foo.Add("key3", true); //Correct - Value is a boolean
foo.Add("key4", new Foobar()); //Compiler error - Value is a Foobar
```

My ultimate goal is to provide a library for other developers. This feature should enable them to define "variables" during runtime and give them a type.

Edit://Firefox' about:config page has something very close to what I want to achieve

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've seen this quite often and thought it was common practice.

Comment: Please read the link I included in the comment. It's not a good practice, and I fix it when I see it.

Comment: What's your *actual* use case? Perhaps if you explain that, people can direct you to a better solution entirely (or maybe the just tell you to go ahead and use `object` and worry about boxing if and when it actually proves to be a performance problem). The dictionary you are looking for does not exist, obviously.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't all of those types Comparable?

Comment: @IronMan84 So you suggest using `Dictionary<string, IComparable>`?

Comment: @IronMan84 This wouldn't prevent from using `Foobar` if it does implement `IComparable`

Comment: Do you consider a wrapper around a dictionary, with something like 3 `Add`s?

Comment: David, did you consider creating a dictionary for each type? you can wrapp these dictionaries into another class. 
One of the most important goals of having generics in the first place is to provide type saftey, having a collection with different types returns us to the dayzs of .NET 1.x were we only had List of object, your approach is kind of back to the past :-) I would consider separate lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not create a fresh new class which implements the IDictionary and uses a Dictionary as a private variable.

Then, in the add methods, you can provide your own logic and fail accordingly

**Sample code**

```
public class MyDic : IDictionary<object, object>
{
    private Dictionary<object, object> privateDic= new Dictionary<object,object>();


    public void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
            throw new ArgumentException();
        privateDic.Add(key, value);
    }
    //Rest of the interface follows
}
```

Comment: Depending on how much this code will change, you could provide 3 separate overloads for the `Add` method, accepting a `value` with type `int`, `string`, or `bool`, respectively. By doing that, type correctness is checked at compile time, not at run time.

Comment: This is probably the best way to go. Thanks a lot

Comment: @dialer: Your solution clearly has the advantage of compile time checking. i do not know if david needs runtime checking like injecting types and

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to:

1. Create a base type for your dictionary values e.g. MyDictionaryBaseType
2. Extend this basic type for each dictionary value type your have e.g. StringDictionryType : MyDictionaryBaseType, IntegerDictionryType : MyDictionaryBaseType...etc.
3. Create a generic dictionary type with MyDictionaryBaseType and limit the type to extend this base type.

This way you limit your dictionry to three specifed types

Comment: @DavidStockinger I guess because it would force you to create your own types for `int`, `bool` and `string` in order to work. Theoretically (i.e. other than that), it's a very good and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the values into wrapper classs like this:

```
class Value
{
}

class TypedValue<T> : Value
{
  public T Val;
}

class IntValue : TypedValue<int>
{
}

class StringValue : TypedValue<string>
{
}

class BoolValue : TypedValue<bool>
{
}

Dictionary<string,Value> foo;

foo.Add("key1", new StringValue{Val="Hello World!"});
```

Another possibility would be to use a Dictionary and do a runtime check for right or wrong types added. I don't think there is a solution without involving boxing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish isn't type-safe as it stands. For example, let's say you have such a dictionary:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<string, (string, int, bool)>();
var x = foo["key1"];
// What type is x? How could the compiler know?
```

One idea would be to devise a container class which can hold one-of either `string`, `int`, or `bool`.

```
public class StringIntBool {
   private bool _isSet;
   private bool _isString;
   public bool IsString {
       get { return _isString; }
   }
   // ...

   private string _innerString;
   public string InnerString {
       get {
           return _innerString;
       }
       set {
           if (_isSet) {
               throw new Exception("StringIntBool is already set");
           }
           _isSet = true;
           _isString = true;
           _innerString = value;
       }
   }

   // etc...
}
```

This is quite ugly, and doesn't really give many benefits.

As an alternative, you could actually store all three values as `object`s, and then use a technique / library like [Functional C#](http://functionalcsharp.codeplex.com/) to perform pattern-matching, like many functional languages can.

```
object x = "str";
int res = x.Match()
    .With<string>(s => s == "str" ? 10 : 20)
    .With<int>(i => i)
    .With<bool>(b => b ? 50 : 60)
    .Return<int>();
```

This pattern of programming is actually pretty common in certain functional language. For example, in SML, you can define a datatype, and then pattern-match it as needed.

```
(* StringIntBool *)
datatype sib = SibString of string | SibInt of int | SibBool of bool

val x = (* some instance of sib *)
val y = case x of
    SibString s => if s = "hello" then 50 else -50
  | SibInt i => i
  | SibBool b => if b then 10 else 20
```

Comment: I think you can do more-or-less the same thing with discriminated unions in F# (I know this question is about C#)